# What are the resistances of the R1 and R2? How to compute?

Tags: transistors, switches, resistance

This is transistor as a switch. I used KSP2222A transistor. How to compute the resistances! Thank you for any help.

[image: This is transistor as a switch. I used KSP2222A transistor. How to compute the resistances! Thank you for any help.]

Comment: As a learning project, I suggest you first specify what you want the circuit to do. In detail. If you have no such requirements, any value(s) will do.

Comment: The LED will lit up if the switch is off.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Any values? You want him to burn up his LED?

Comment: @DigitalNinja do you know how to compute the resistances?

Comment: @RafaelChristianS.Aguilar I think you've been down voted because we need more info, like the LED and transistor specs. This is pretty basic though and your answer can be found with Google research.

Comment: Your schematic is upside down. It's very difficult to look at.

Comment: Should be closed - no research.

Comment: There is an additional design flaw in this circuit in that it consumes an unnecessary amount of current with the LED unlit. Although the resistor calculations in the answer below are correct, you should consider designing around a standard open collector circuit and invert the switch logic using a high value pull-up and switch the base to ground.

Comment: @digitalNinja without any specs, how can you be sure that burning the LED isn't the purpose of the circuit?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Touche ;)

Comment: @Rafael when you just require that "the LED will lit up when the switch is off" you can leave out R1 and T1 (and even the switch!). And you must state which current the LED requires to lit up. Note that I am trying to get you to realy state what you want. Of course we can guess (see EM Fields answer), but that will not learn you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since the transistor's collector-to-emitter junction will be in  cutoff and the LED will be ON when SW1 is open, R2 must be sized such that, with forward current through the LED, R2 drops the difference between the supply voltage and the LED's forward voltage when SW1 is open. Using Ohm's law, the calculation goes like this:

$$ Rs =\frac{Vs - Vled}{Iled}  $$

where Rs is the resistance of the ballast resistor (R2), Vs is the supply voltage, Vled is the LED's forward voltage, and Iled is the LED's forward current.

Then, assuming a white LED dropping 3.5 volts with a forward current of 20 milliamperes through it, we can write:

$$ Rs =\frac{Vs - Vled}{Iled} = \frac{9V - 3.5V}{0.02A} = 275\text{ ohms}  $$

On the other hand, with SW1 closed the transistor will be turned ON, and the current which would have otherwise gone through the LED will now be diverted to ground through the transistor's collector-to-emitter junction, turning the LED OFF.

In order to turn the transistor ON, current must be forced through its base-to-emitter junction, that current depending on the current gain (beta) of the transistor and the current through its collector-to-emitter junction.

For many switching applications beta is forced to 10, which means that no matter what the native gain of the transistor, the current into the base is made to be one tenth of the collector current.

In this instance, then, with 20 milliamperes of collector current and a forced beta of 10, the base current should be 2 milliamperes.

The base-to-emitter junction of a 2N2222 looks like a diode, so it'll drop about 0.7 volts with current through it and, with a supply voltage of 9 volts, R1 must drop about 8.3 volts with 2 milliamperes through it and the base-to-emitter diode of the transistor.

Again reverting to Ohm's law, we can write:

$$ R1 =\frac{Vs - Vbe}{Ib} = \frac{9V -0.7V}{0.002A}= 4150 \text{ ohms}   $$

Neither the ballast resistor nor the base resistor are all that critical, and the closest E24 value would be fine.